# Could to Get Size Screen When Orientation Changed With Static Method on Java Android?

Tags: android, screen-size, android-screen

How to get Size of Screen Android when Orientation has been changed?

```
public static final Size getDisplaySize(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    WindowManager winManager = activity.getWindowManager();
    if (winManager != null) {
        Point displaySize = new Point(0, 0);
        winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
        displayScreenSize = new Size(displaySize.x, displaySize.y);
    }
    return displayScreenSize;
}
```

Its code just get last size display when if screen is changed. Its not work too if use this code:

```
private static Size displayScreenSize;
public static final Size getDisplaySize(@NonNull Context context) {
    new OrientationEventListener(context) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            if (winManager != null) {
                Point displaySize = new Point(0, 0);
                winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                displayScreenSize = new Size(displaySize.x, displaySize.y);
            }
            displayScreenSize = new Size(0, 0);
        }
    };
    return displayScreenSize;
}
```